# SQL Server connection with Unity

Tags: c#, sql-server, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to connect my Unity project to SQL Server. I have connected my Windows Forms application in Visual Studio 2017 successfully. And I think if copy the exact code in a unity script my goal should happen. I have imported `System.Data.Dll V3.5` to my assets and using `unity2018.2.1.f1`. I am using the following script trying to first open the connection but I get the error below.

```cs
void Start () 
{
    try
    {
        string ConnString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-PVB5MHG;Initial Catalog=UnityTest;User ID=legend;Password=legend";
        SqlConnection MyConn = new SqlConnection(ConnString);
        MyConn.Open();
        Debug.Log("Connection opened !");
    }
    catch(System.Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.Log(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Server does not exist or
>   connection refused.
>
> Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsInternalException: Server does not exist or connection refused.
>
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used.
>
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP,
>   Boolean requireSocketPolicy) [0x00000] in :0
>   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket+Worker.Connect () [0x00000] in :0
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsComm..ctor (System.String dataSource, Int32
>   port, Int32 packetSize, Int32 timeout, TdsVersion tdsVersion) [0x00000] in :0
>   at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.Tds..ctor (System.String dataSource, Int32
>   port, Int32 packetSize, Int32 timeout, TdsVersion tdsVersion) [0x00000] in :0
>   at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.Tds70..ctor (System.String server, Int32 port,
>   Int32 packetSize, Int32 timeout, TdsVersion version) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.Tds80..ctor
>   (System.String server, Int32 port, Int32 packetSize, Int32 timeout)
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsConnectionPoolManager.CreateConnection
>   (Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsConnectionInfo info) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsConnectionPool.GetConnection () [0x00000] in
>   :0    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open ()
>   [0x00000] in :0    --- End of inner exception stack
>   trace ---   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open () [0x00000]
>   in :0    at DB.Start () [0x00010] in
>   D:\UnityProjects2018\DataBaseTest1\Assets\DB.cs:15 
>   UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object) DB:Start() (at Assets/DB.cs:20)

Comment: Connecting to a non-embedded database is generally not something you want to do directly in the kinds of applications you make with Unity. Typically you create a service as a "data layer" and make http calls to it instead of direct connection to the database.

Comment: I believe Integrated Security only works on Windows. Try creating a user on SQL Server and add it to your connection string.

Also, are you sure SQL Server is running on the machine? Don't you have to replace localhost?

Comment: @tvdias first , thanks for the comment. i just created a user and changed the connection string. again works well in visual studio but same error in unity. and i edited the code, could you please check again

Comment: While we are not sure of the bigger picture here, I highly recommend you do not embed your SQL connection data directly into the app and have all your clients connect directly to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use ODBC in Unity due to limitations in Mono. Use http://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient instead.

Your specific error is related to the differences in how machine names are resolved in Mono versus the ancient version of .Net framework of the WinForms era. `DESKTOP-PVB5MHG` will not be a valid DNS name, while Mono only uses DNS to resolve `Data Source`.